# java.net.URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web.xml"); returns null

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss6.x

```
java.net.URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("web.xml");

String filePath = r.getFile();
log.info("filePath :"+filePath);
System.out.println("filePath :"+filePath);
String result = new File(new File(new File(filePath).getParent()).getParent()).getParent();
System.out.println("result :"+result);
```

When running on JBoss5 it has a value containing a path of application, but when I am running it on JBoss6 it has a null value

Comment: is `r` null on JBoss6?

Comment: Yes r is null on Jboss 6